# Golang context in http request when making bulk calls

Tags: go, range, timeout

I am looking for to understand the behaviour I should expect when making http calls using go standard library with Context timeout.

I understand that if I do this :

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 200*time.Millisecond)
defer cancel()
req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, "http://localhost:8080", nil)
```

That specific request will TO in 200 milliseconds. That works quite well and I get it.

My doubt is, what happens if I do this:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 200*time.Millisecond)
defer cancel()
for loop with a range from 1 to 20 {
  req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, "http://localhost:8080", nil)
}
```

So in the latter example I am doing a bunch of requests using that very context. Will all requests timeout with 200 milliseconds individually, or will they start to fail after 200 milliseconds have passed from the moment I started ranging over?

Note:

```
FATHER_CONTEXT, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 200*time.Millisecond)

defer cancel()
for loop with a range from 1 to 20 {
  ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(FATHER_CONTEXT, 200*time.Millisecond)
  req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, "http://localhost:8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: The context is shared. When it expires, it expires for all requests. All requests will fail 200ms after you created the context.

Comment: thanks sir! and what happens if my new context is crated from a previous context? will the father context reset its timeout too?

Comment: I added an example of what I mean

Comment: That is explain in the docs. "Child contexts" cancel when the parent context cancels. That's what contexts are _for_.

Answer (score 1):

From [Context Documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/context#pkg-overview)

> The WithCancel, WithDeadline, and WithTimeout functions take a Context
> (the parent) and return a derived Context (the child) and a
> CancelFunc. Calling the CancelFunc cancels the child and its children,
> removes the parent's reference to the child, and stops any associated
> timers

So the context is shared by the child and its children. All requests will be timeout after 200 milliseconds.